# WPF- Compile error on referencing a Resource Dictionary file

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

**Question**: When I reference the following `Resource Dictionary` file in `MainWindow.xaml` file (shown below), why do I get the following compile error?

> > CustomWindowStyle resource not found

**Remark**:

1. I'm following this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1205642/WPF-Resource-Dictionary-Basics) where the `Creating A Resource Dictionary File` section is also showing the exact procedure that I am using on how to reference Resource Dictionary in `MainWindow.xaml`
2. As shown in the image below, `VS2019` does CORRECCTLY recognize `CustomWindowStyle` when I type `Style="{StaticResource ....}` line in `MainWindow.xaml`. But at the compile time (as shown in image 2 below), it throws the above error.
3. I am using `.NET Core 3.1`. I'm not sure if the issue is related to .NET Core

**When typing the line Style="{StaticResource ....}** the intellisense correctly shows the option of selecting CustomWindowStyle:

[image]

**At the compile time, the error shows up**:

[image]
.

**WindowStyle.xaml**:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="WPF_OctDelete.WindowStyle"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_OctDelete">

    <Style x:Key="CustomWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="30"
                              CornerRadius="4"
                              GlassFrameThickness="0"
                              NonClientFrameEdges="None"
                              ResizeBorderThickness="5"
                              UseAeroCaptionButtons="False" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="5,30,5,5">
                            <AdornerDecorator>
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </AdornerDecorator>
                        </Border>

                        <DockPanel Height="30"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   LastChildFill="False">

                            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                       FontSize="16"
                                       Foreground="White"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" />

                            <Button x:Name="btnClose"
                                    Width="15"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    Click="CloseClick"
                                    Content="X"
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                    WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" />


                            <Button x:Name="btnRestore"
                                    Width="15"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    Click="MaximizeRestoreClick"
                                    Content="#"
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                    WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" />

                            <Button x:Name="btnMinimize"
                                    Width="15"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
                                    Click="MinimizeClick"
                                    Content="_"
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                    WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" />
                        </DockPanel>

                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_OctDelete.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_OctDelete"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Style="{StaticResource CustomWindowStyle}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="WindowStyle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="Test"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Afair I had a similar problem. A workaround was to use it as `DynamicResource` instead of StaticResource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XAML processor reads the XAML file from top to bottom so by the time it tries to resolve the `CustomWindowStyle` resource, it hasn't yet loaded the `ResourceDictionary`.

You could easily fix this by setting the `Resources` property *before* you set the `Style` property:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_OctDelete.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_OctDelete"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="WindowStyle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Style>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="CustomWindowStyle"/>
    </Window.Style>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="Test"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The order matters.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the reason for compile error - that was important for me. Now I know order matters.

Answer (score 3):

Your resource is being loaded after the window is loaded and so it cannot find the resource during the window loading event. So your method isn't going to work that way.

You need to put that resource in your App.xaml file, see - [How to Set the Source of an Image in XAML and in Code Behind to an image in another project in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64388106/how-to-set-the-source-of-an-image-in-xaml-and-in-code-behind-to-an-image-in-anot/64399543#64399543)

In your case (in App.xaml) - '

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="WindowStyle.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And then you can use your key in the Window -

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_OctDelete.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_OctDelete"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Style="{StaticResource CustomWindowStyle}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <!--Rest of your UI Elements-->
</Window>
```

No need to add resources to your window, since its added to the main app file. That resource will be available across your entire project (available for other windows/controls)

(**Edit:** further clarification - When you add something as a "StaticResource" to your window style, but load the actual resource later, the window "loaded" event is not going to pick it up. Another solution is to refer your style as "DynamicResource", so the style during the "loaded" event is not static and will be updated when it captures the new resource.)

Comment: The question was more specific to my curiosity as to why referencing Resource Dictionary inside `MainWindow` not working. I had already tried it in the `App.xaml` with `Source="pack://application:,,,/WPF_OctDelete;component/WindowStyle.xaml"` and it had compiled fine. I'm sorry, I should have mentioned it in my post. But thank you for sharing your knowledge so others can benefit from it, as well. You do deserve my upvote +1 for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @nam i had answered your question - look at the top most line of my answer. Unfortunate for me, you didnt read the first line of my answer, it explains exactly what you asked. Anyway, ive added more info.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out another possible solution. Keep up the good work. I admire you on sharing your knowledge.